# Authenticate GCP Service Account via environment /variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, subprocess

Authentication for a GCP Service Account usually requires a .json file containing the credentials.

The command is: gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file "path to .json file"

If the above command is run as a subprocess in Python3 how could one pass the --key-file by storing the contents of the .json in memory. The requirement is to not have/create the file on local storage.

Comment: You cannot specify an in-memory JSON file. Specifying secrets via the command line is also not secure. Your question does include context on where you are running this command. Note: The CLI stores the credentials on the disk, which breaks your goal.

Comment: @JohnHanley The json file is stored in a credential store or some private repository.

The Python script (which is capable of fetching the contents of the json and storing it in a variable or environment variable) would run in a Linux environment and would utilize the subprocess module of Python to run gcloud commands.

The only issue is the storage of the json file locally (on disk).

Comment: @john-hanley is correct. If you don't use `gcloud` and don't use Python `subprocess` (which is an imperfect solution) you can implement (almost) any `gcloud` functionality using Google's e.g. Python SDKs directly. `gcloud` is a Python app that (mostly) uses Google's Python SDKs anyway so you're also saving using Python to run Python to make Google API calls. Using the SDKs, you can load Service Account keys as JSON or a dict. Presumably your credential store has an SDK too. See: https://googleapis.dev/python/google-api-core/latest/auth.html#service-accounts

Comment: Using the SDK would work for sure, from the examples that I've seen.

Was just curious about the subprocess approach. Thank you for the answers!

Comment: 1) If you are running on a Google Cloud compute service, you do not need to load your own credentials (service account JSON key file). Use the attached service account. 2) Otherwise, drop the idea of using the Python subprocess Plus the CLI and code in Python. You can load the service account JSON key file from memory, but the attached service account is still more secure. 3) For development, you will have credentials stored on disk as you have a catch-22. To read credentials securely, you need credentials.

Comment: most of the time,  you don't need key file, even locally, your user account is enough. You might have to review your security management instead of trying to perform strange things.

Comment: The idea is to have a service account in place which can be used by multiple scripts instead of it being tied to an individual account.

Comment: You have not provided details on where your code is running. That means which Google Cloud service. If you are outside the cloud then you will need to provide either a service account JSON file or use the CLI to authorize. Inside the cloud, you can use the service's credentals.